# Knockout JS Validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am a newbie in Knockout JS. i want to apply validations in KO. i have used plugin knockout.validation.min.js . I have implemented it like this but not working

My View Model

```
 $(document).ready(function myfunction() {

        ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeKoViewModel());

    })
    var EmployeeKoViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
        self.EmpId = ko.observable()
        self.Name = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: "please enter employee name " } });
        self.City = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: "please enter employee city " } });
        self.Employees = ko.observableArray();


             //GetEmployees();
            var EmpData = {
                EmpId: self.EmpId,
                Name: self.Name,
                City: self.City,

            };
            function GetEmployees() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Employee/About",
                }).done(function (data) {

                    self.Employees(data);
                }).error(function (ex) {
                    alert("Error");
                });
            }
        self.save = function () {
            var EmployeeKoViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
            if (!EmployeeKoViewModel.errors().length <= 0) {
                EmployeeKoViewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Employee/Save",
                data: ko.toJSON(EmpData),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    self.EmpId(data.EmpId);
                    GetEmployees();

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
        };
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzwt3jqk/2/) it is working when i comment GetEmployees() method but not working with it

Comment: It might help you! http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/3238/

Comment: it working fine check it https://jsfiddle.net/vzwt3jqk/5/ .cheers

Comment: Yeah it does but when i checked again in local it haven worked and guess what i finnaly changed my validation js file it worked

Comment: humm ! go ahead &  accept @dotnetom answer . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line

```
var EmployeeKoViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
```

you are trying to create a variable, but the syntax is like creating an object with a property which is of course invalid. In order to fix this you can initialize your object first:

```
var EmployeeKoViewModel = {};
EmployeeKoViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
if (!EmployeeKoViewModel.errors().length <= 0) {
    EmployeeKoViewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
    return false;
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzwt3jqk/)

Comment: I dont know why but its no workinG.In fiddle its working fine

Comment: @Vivekh Take what is in jsFiddle as a starting point and start adding your logic step by step, and you should see at what point it starts failing

Comment: Now it also worked regadless of writing var EmployeeKoViewModel = {}; with the new JS file Thanks